# using javascript, how can i make it possible to look up multiple symbols simultaneously and display prices for each in a table-like format on the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, node.js, ajax

I've built this application that allows the user to enter one stock ticker symbol and it displays price information about the stock. But now I want to make it possible to look up multiple symbols simultaneously (separated by commas) and display prices for each in a table-like format on the page. how can I do that using javascript?  code for the application I've built is below

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Stocks</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link href="https://bootswatch.com/4/simplex/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
   <style>
   #stock {
     display: flex;
background:#f4f4f4;
     padding:10px;
     margin-bottom: 10px;
   }
   </style>
  </head>


<body>



  <div class="container">

    <div class="searchContainer">
      <h1>Enter symbol</h1>
      <p class="lead">Enter a a symbol to fetch a price </p>
      <input type="text" id ="search" class="form-control" placeholder="Stock symbol...">
    </div>
    <br>
    <button type="button" id="searchstock" class="btn btn-info">Get Stock Price</button>
    <br>
    <br>
    <div id="stock"></div>


  </div>
  <!-- /.container -->

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.js" integrity="sha256-16cdPddA6VdVInumRGo6IbivbERE8p7CQR3HzTBuELA=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/main.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
<script> 
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#searchstock').on('click', function(){

    let requestData = $('#search').val();
    let resultElement = $('#stock');
    // Make request to rest API
    $.ajax({

      url:'https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=BATCH_STOCK_QUOTES&symbols=' + requestData + '&apikey=SB1CZMKQ6Q5283QZ',
      method: 'get',
      data:{symbols:requestData},
      dataType: 'json',
      success: function (data){
        console.log(data);
        resultElement.html( data["Stock Quotes"][0]["1. symbol"] + '<hr>' 
      + ' Price : ' + data["Stock Quotes"][0]["2. price"])
        // resultElement.html('Price : ' + data["Stock Quotes"][0]["2. price"])


      }




  });
});
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would just change

```
$('#searchstock').on('click', function(){
```

to

```
$('#search').on('keyup', function() {
```

and add a loop in success function which concats symbol, price and timeStamps as a table rows and cells

```
var table;
for (let i = 0; i < data['Stock Quotes'].length; i++) {
    let symbol = '<td>' + data['Stock Quotes'][i]['1. symbol'] + '</td>';
    let price = '<td>' + data['Stock Quotes'][i]['2. price'] + '</td>';
    let timeStamp = '<td>' + data['Stock Quotes'][i]['4. timestamp'] + '</td>';
    table += '<tr>' + symbol + price + timeStamp + '</tr>';
}
document.getElementById('stockList').innerHTML = table;
```

Of course, you also need to add table in HTML

```
<table id="stockList"></table>
```

The output will be:

A   67.5000 2018-03-02 15:59:58
B   60.0450 2018-03-02 15:54:37
C   73.6850 2018-03-02 15:59:58

Comment: this doesn't work, you can edit my question so you can run it with run code system

Comment: If I understood correctly it should looks like this [codepen](https://codepen.io/innocent2102/pen/jZorZe?editors=1111)

Comment: thanks, it works but whenever I click the button, it says undefined on top then it gives the price. what can I do to get rid of the word "undefined"?

Comment: The button is no longer need when you search items dynamically. But undefined value comes from different case. HTML tried to show empty value from table - check updated [code](https://codepen.io/innocent2102/pen/ddEpVd) to analyze.

Moreover, this code is not very effective, because you make a request each time when you press key (even space or comma) which is unnecessary. I would suggest you to send request after 400ms time when you stop typing.

Comment: oh i see.
but the project i'm working on must have a button to fetch results. is there any way you can get rid of the "undefined" while using the button?

Comment: I've already get rid of this in previous comment. Hold the link with button fetching data [codepen](https://codepen.io/innocent2102/pen/ddEpVd)

Comment: thank you!! you're the best! how can I make the result more table like? with symbol rows and price columns  ?

Comment: Could you explain more accurately? Also, If you satisfied with answer, please tick the mark.

Comment: i figure it out. thanks for your help and I clicked the mark